# Deep linked values for a page in Laravel database models

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.1

A `page` has multiple elements and they are linked using the `page_to_elements` table. Each `element` has multiple `element_fields` and are linked using the `element_to_element_fields`. Each `element_field` has a type and are linked using the `element_to_element_fields` table. The values of each `element_field` within the element has a value (eitehr in value_char, value_text or value_num) that is stored in the `element_values` table.

Below is how the database structure is:

```
pages:
id|name

elements:
id|name

element_fields_types (sql_type can be char, text or num):
id|name|sql_type

element_fields (names can be title, intro, content, link, number, etc etc):
id:element_field_type_id|name

element_to_element_fields:
id|element_id|element_field_id

page_to_elements:
id|page_id|element_id

element_values:
id|page_id|element_id|page_to_element_id|element_field_id|value_char|value_text|value_num
```

What I am looking for is a good `hasManyToMany` solution to get all values when I request a page id. I now have multiple loops and array creations to get a structure like this (where the values are from the correct column name based on what was set in the `element_fields`):

```
$page = array(
    'elements' => array(
        [0] => array(
            'element_name_here' => array(
                'fields' => array(
                    [0] => array(
                        'field_name_here' => 'Field value',
                        'field_name_here' => 'Field value',
                        'field_name_here' => 'Field value',
                        'field_name_here' => 'Field value'
                    ),
                    [1] => array(
                        'field_name_here' => 'Field value',
                        'field_name_here' => 'Field value',
                        'field_name_here' => 'Field value',
                        'field_name_here' => 'Field value'
                    ),
                    [2] => array(
                        'field_name_here' => 'Field value',
                        'field_name_here' => 'Field value',
                        'field_name_here' => 'Field value',
                        'field_name_here' => 'Field value'
                    ),
                )
            )
        ),
        [1] => array(
            'element_name_here' => array(
                'fields' => array(
                    [0] => array(
                        'field_name_here' => 'Field value',
                        'field_name_here' => 'Field value',
                        'field_name_here' => 'Field value',
                        'field_name_here' => 'Field value'
                    ),
                    [1] => array(
                        'field_name_here' => 'Field value',
                        'field_name_here' => 'Field value',
                        'field_name_here' => 'Field value',
                        'field_name_here' => 'Field value'
                    ),
                    [2] => array(
                        'field_name_here' => 'Field value',
                        'field_name_here' => 'Field value',
                        'field_name_here' => 'Field value',
                        'field_name_here' => 'Field value'
                    ),
                )
            )
        ),

    )
);
```

So I need something like below to produce above array:

```
$page = Page::find($id);
print_r($page->getValues->toArray());
```

I have some experience with belongsToMany or hasManyToMany, but never this deep.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you got all your relationships set up in your models?

Comment: Yes kind of. So element_fields has a relation ship with elements etc. Also the database relationships are set. Just need the deep link from page all the way to the values

Comment: Did you see the following option? https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through

Comment: @davejal Can this be with more than one intermediate model?

Comment: well, first of all, your element_values table has wrong structure. To determine a specific element on a specific page page_to_element_id is enough, so adding "page" and "element" fields is wrong. 

Second. are all 3 types of element always available for each page? in both cases - the changes have to be made.

Comment: to put it simple - right now you have a possibility to create a value for non-existing page-element-element_type combo, which is wrong

Comment: @GodlyHedgehog The element fields table should be there to determine the type of data that has been stored and how the fields are used in the front end. Like you can have field types 'title', 'api', 'description', 'slug', 'content', 'class' etc etc etc

Comment: @AlvinBakker then you are missing 1 table which would consist of

id | page_to_element_id | element_to_element_fields_id

so that it connects separate element with certain element fleld set

ps. a bit busy now, so cannot test it properly.

Comment: @GodlyHedgehog A page has elements (`page_to_elements`), each element has fields (`element_to_element_fields`) and each field has a value (`element_values`), so why do I need to make an extra link as you suggest to link page_to_element with element_to_element_fields?

Comment: @AlvinBakker right now you have 2 fields (except of unrelevant page and element field): page_to_element_id and element_field_id. with this structure you CANNOT ensure that the selected element has the requested type (for this you must have element_to_element_fields_id in values table). After you changed the field to element_to_element_fields_id, again, you cannot ensure that element_id of page_to_element and element_to_element_fields are the same (try imaging filling those tables "by hand"). Therefore, you need a cross-table that will give you access to full chain page->element->field->type .

Comment: @AlvinBakker , of course this is the way without changing table structure. you could rework some tables for such case

Comment: @GodlyHedgehog OK, many thanks for this explanation. I will try it out and let you know the outcome

Answer (score 2):

Your schema is quite complex, but I believe you can achieve the structure you want with eager-loading the relations and leveraging collection methods.

```
<?php

class Page extends Eloquent
{
    public function elements()
    {
       return $this->belongsToMany(Element::class, 'page_to_elements');
    }

    public function values()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Value::class);
    }

    public function getValues()
    {
        return $this->values()
            // Eager-load the value element, the value field and its type
            ->with(['element', 'field.type'])->get()

            // Group all the values by page element
            ->groupBy('page_to_element_id')->values()

            // Group the values of each page element by the element name
            ->groupBy(function ($values) {
                return $values->first()->element->name;
            })

            // Iterate each page element
            ->map(function ($values, $element) {

                // Make an array with the element name as key and its fields as value
                return [
                    $element => [

                        // Group the values by element field
                        'fields' => $values->groupBy('element_field_id')->values()

                            // Make an array with the field names and values for each element field
                            ->map(function ($values) {
                                return $values->pluck('value', 'field.name')->all();
                            })->all(),
                    ],
                ];
            })->all();
    }
}

class Element extends Eloquent
{
    public function pages()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Page::class, 'page_to_elements');
    }

    public function fields()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Field::class, 'element_to_element_fields');
    }

    public function values()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Value::class);
    }
}

class Field extends Eloquent
{
    public function type()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Type::class);
    }

    public function values()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Value::class);
    }
}

class Type extends Eloquent
{
    public function fields()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Field::class);
    }
}

class Value extends Eloquent
{
    public function page()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Page::class);
    }

    public function element()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Element::class);
    }

    public function field()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Field::class);
    }

    public function getValueAttribute()
    {
        $type = $this->field->type->sql_type;

        return $this->getAttribute('value_'.$type);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanx, I will try this tomorrow

Comment: I really will recommend implementing the repository pattern

Comment: @VictorH.Avelar What do you mean?

Comment: @sebdesign I tried this and it comes a bit close, but fields are all jumbled up and no correct values are fetched. I will try and figure out the logic and see if it will make sence

Comment: @AlvinBakker In your example I'm not sure what the fields array keys are, so I assumed they correspond to the `element_field_id`. Let me know if I can help you out.

Comment: @sebdesign The keys are the api names of the element fields. For example `$res['title'] => 'Hello world!'` or `$res['slug'] => '/hello-world` where the keys are the API names